# My UpdateCursor is not working. The attribute table of my new shapefile is not updating

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor, python-2.7

I am new to arcpy. I am trying to do a few things with a shapefile. First I created a new shapefile with specific dataset that I wanted to work on. So far everything works until the UpdateCursor. When it runs, it doesn't update the attribute table of the output file (outfc). Am I missing something?

Here is what I'm trying to do:

All of the values that are in the “SPCOMP” field should be put into related individual species fields, and leave the rest of species fields to 0. For example, if the “SPCOMP” = “Pj 60Pt 30Bw 10”, that means that Pj = 60, Pt = 30, Bw = 10. Then 60 should go under “PJ”, 30 goes under “PT”, and 10 goes under “BW”.

Here is the code:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.overwriteOutput = True

env.workspace = 'G:\\School\\GGR386\\FRMG_Coding_Exercise'

infc = 'ftg_true_all.shp'

outfc = 'G:\\School\\GGR386\\FRMG_Coding_Exercise\\New\\ftg_true_all_change.shp'

where_clause = """ "TRTMTHD1" = 'NATURAL' OR "TRTMTHD1" = 'PLANT' """

arcpy.Select_analysis(infc, outfc, where_clause)

in_field = 'SPCOMP'
fields = arcpy.ListFields(outfc)
field_list = []

sc = arcpy.SearchCursor(outfc, [in_field])

for row in sc:
    s = str(row.getValue(in_field))
    s_stripped_cap = s.replace(' ', '').upper()
    i, j = 0, 0
    spcomp = []

    if s_stripped_cap[0].isdigit() == True:
        data_type = 'int'
    else:
        data_type = 'alphabet'
    for char in s_stripped_cap:
        if char.isdigit() == True and data_type != 'int':
            spcomp.append(s_stripped_cap[i:j])
            i = j
            data_type = 'int'
        elif char.isalpha() == True and data_type != 'alphabet':
            spcomp.append(s_stripped_cap[i:j])
            i = j
            data_type = 'alphabet'
        j += 1 

    for f_name in fields:
        if f_name.type != "String" and len(f_name.name) <= 2:
            field_list.append(f_name.name)

        spuc = arcpy.UpdateCursor(outfc, [field_list])
        for r in spuc:
            for i in range(len(spcomp)):
                if spcomp[i].isalpha() and spcomp[i] == r:
                    sp_num = int(spcomp[i + 1])
                    r[0] = sp_num
                    spuc.updateRow(r)

del row
del sc
del r
del spuc
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  Here you are including your whole code which makes your question too broad.

Comment: Some comments I can offer on your code is that it seems odd that you are using old style cursors (arcpy.SearchCursor and arcpy.UpdateCursor) rather than arcpy.da.SearchCursor and arcpy.da.UpdateCursor from the Data Access module.  It also seems odd to run an UpdateCursor within a SearchCursor, but if you really do want that coding pattern then I suggest you simplify the work done by your UpdateCursor to just being to write the same string to each feature.  Once that's working, it will be easier to start making your code more complicated again.

Comment: Just when you think you undestand I/O Cursors ... https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/337440/151035

Comment: x='Pj 60Pt 30Bw 10'
pj_name = x.split()[0]
pj_val = x.split()[1][0:2]
pt_name = x.split()[1][2:4]
pt_val = x.split()[2][0:2]
bw_name = x.split()[2][2:4]
bw_val = x.split()[3][0:2]
y=[x,pj_name,pj_val,pt_name,pt_val,bw_name,bw_val]
for arg in y:
  print arg

Comment: @PolyGeo ... odd to you might indicate that you are the exception and not the rule. The old and new cursors work just fine in this context, and running nested cursors is preferred in certain contexts. By placing the question on hold, you limit the channels of communication to the individual seeking help which is why they came here in the first place. I would also argue that by providing more code than a snippet, the submitter has provided a clearer context around which potential responders can constrain their response.