# GDB lock remains when a layer is removed from the MXD

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, lock

I have a script which removes a layer from the MXD, and then re-creates the feature from scratch in a GDB and adds the layer back in.

If I remove the layer manually before running the script, it runs fine. But if I remove the layer in the script, the script later fails when trying to re-create the GDB due to a lock. This is resolved by reloading the MXD.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\RouteSmart_Work\Tools
>   and Utilities\Python - Street Assignment
>   Visualiser\StreetAssignment.py", line 60, in 
>       arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(outputFolder, "StreetAssignments.gdb")   File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 16594, in
>   CreateFileGDB
>       raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function. Failed to execute (CreateFileGDB).

I've tried implementing arcpy.Compact_management (credit to [StacyR](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31034/remove-lock-on-feature-class/32375#32375) from another and gc.collect() but these still don't seem to clear the lock. Could anyone advise if I'm missing anything? The script is meant to be run frequently, without the need to remove the layer each time.

```
def clearWSLocks(inputWS):
  '''Attempts to clear locks on a workspace, returns stupid message.'''
  if all([arcpy.Exists(inputWS), arcpy.Compact_management(inputWS), arcpy.Exists(inputWS)]):
    return 'Workspace (%s) clear to continue...' % inputWS
  else:
    return '!!!!!!!! ERROR WITH WORKSPACE %s !!!!!!!!' % inputWS

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

servLoc_layer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
streets_layer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
outputFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

# Remove the layer if it's already in the data frame
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
if arcpy.Exists("FC"):  # Use name rather than layer object in case name doesn't exist
    lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer("FC")  # Create layer object in order to remove it
    arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    del lyr, df, mxd

outGDB = os.path.join(outputFolder, "GDB.gdb") # Geodatabase

xyLineOutput = os.path.join(outGDB,"FC")
if arcpy.Exists(xyLineOutput):
    arcpy.Delete_management(xyLineOutput)

gc.collect()

if arcpy.Exists(outGDB):
    arcpy.AddMessage(clearWSLocks(outGDB))
    arcpy.Delete_management(outGDB)
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(outputFolder, "GDB.gdb")
```

EDIT:

In this instance I've instructed the user to remove the layer manually before running the script, to keep the one GDB as the workspace. It's only a small geoprocessing task, so the data management will be simple. I will bear Vince's comment in mind for the future.

Comment: There are several different kinds of locks. Is your code sample missing an `arcpy.env.workspace = ...`?

Comment: You need to delete the gdb or just the feature class?  Reason I ask is maybe you are getting that error because you have other locked layers in the gdb.

Comment: @Vince, I haven't used workspace as I use full paths instead. Could the use of a workspace prevent this?

Comment: @artwork21 - very good point, but there's nothing else in the gdb. The script will remove the FC from the gdb leaving an empty gdb, but I cannot even delete it in ArcCatalog until I come out of the MXD

Comment: What happens if you close ArcCatalog and just have the ArcMap open with it, 1. remove the fc from ArcMap, 2. delete the fc in the Catalog tree in ArcMap.  Does it allow you delete the fc then?

Comment: I suspect you have uncollected references within the Python framework which are preserving locks. What you are trying to do is so fraught with risk that I would never attempt it. Instead I would create a *differently* named FGDB in the same directory or an identically named FGDB in a *different* directory (for the record, I would ***never*** name a file geodatabase "GDB").

Comment: @artwork21, yep it works fine when I remove the layer/FC manually, just not when I remove it as part of the script

Comment: @Vince, thanks for your insight. As it is meant to be re-run several times this might end up quite messy. Presumably it would also work if I keep the same GDB and create a new FC? Or would the GDB lock prevent from adding to the GDB? (nb I just named it "GDB" for demonstrative purposes, but thanks for the tip :-)

Comment: Can you try your code in the python console in ArcMap (keep ArcCatalog closed), to remove the fc from the map, delete only the fc, (do not delete the gdb) and recreate the fc?

Comment: I can't tell what your purpose is in this exercise.  I've been writing import and export utilities for nearly thirty years, and I've ***never*** needed to replace the existing container to which multiple references already exist to recreate the data.  The usual pattern is to truncate existing data and append in situ.  If the schema changes, then drop, recreate as an empty table, and append. If I need to recreate the container, it's done in a different parent directory (usually with a release-based name).

Comment: @Mike please [edit] your question to include new information rather than commenting.  Comments are for potential answerers to request clarification or additional info, your response should be as edits to the question.