# Weird schema lock issue

Tags: file-geodatabase, python-3, lock, schema-locks

I wrote a Python script that produces several output features layers in separate `.gdb`'s. As I am testing and modifying my code, I generally go into arcCatalog, find the .gdb under which the feature sits, and delete that feature from the .gdb (leaving the .gdb intact) before rerunning my script. This works fine for all of the feature layers except one. I get a `schema lock` error because the "file is open in a Python script." I literally have to close my Python IDE (Spyder running from Anaconda) and then go back and delete the feature from ArcCatalog. Any reasons why this is happening and suggestions on how I can resolve it?

Comment: Are you using background geoprocessing for your script? This can cause strange lock issues with fgdbs, maybe not like yours.

Comment: I don't think so (not by design). How can I check?

Comment: Question for clarification: Is the Schema Lock always on the *last* .gdb in your script? -- If that is the case you could make a "junk.gbd" and point your script at that for the last iteration and make this issue moot. -- If this works I'll change my comment into an answer.

Comment: Hmmm, I'll try that and see.

Comment: For future reference, since it seems you got a real answer, check your Geoprocessing options in ArcMap. There is a checkbox/toggle for enabling background processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this general type problem has been around since forever.

[Remove Lock on Feature Class](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31034/remove-lock-on-feature-class)

^That answer has a bit of code to add to your block that seems to work for *Schema* and *Read Locks*.

The last solution (as of 8-29-2018) over here on the ESRI Community at GeoNet says essentially what I suggested in my comment - to make scratch or junk .gdb to absorb the bug in the system. 
[Trouble Removing Schema Lock after arcpy](https://community.esri.com/thread/196582-trouble-removing-schema-lock-after-arcpymakefeaturelayer-pro-only)

And yes, it does seem to be a bug with no active intention of getting it fixed because, well... ESRI, and there are a few mildly annoying work-arounds.
It's even been officially classed as a "bug".
[Bug BUG-000086232](https://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDA4NjIzMg==)

This is something that was proposed in February of 2011 to enhance the experience using Python in a geospatial environment. With no action so far we can expect there never to be. But never is a long time so, if you're young enough, you might be surprised at a software fix one day.

[Expose Schema Lock Removal to Python](https://community.esri.com/ideas/3226-expose-schema-lock-removal-to-python)

Comment: This was exactly the answer I was looking for! Thanks. I'll try the simple fix with the junk.gdb first.